# Implement a Set class using an array

Tags: java, set, dynamic-arrays

My Java assignment is to implement a **set class** by using an **array**.

The assignment won't allow me import the set class from the library, so I have to make it on my own. When I tried to print out the array, it prints out numbers in repeats, **not unique numbers**. I don't know where the problem is, so if you guys can find any errors in my code, it would be great. I tried to add numbers **2, 3**, and **4** to the set, so the result **should be** `2 3 4`, but the code shows me `2 3 2 3 2`.

I think the source of the problem is from the **add method** from the set class, but I don't know what the problem is exactly.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Set implements SetInterface
{

    private int[] set;
    private int size;
    private int capacity;

    public Set(int c)
    {
        capacity = c;
        set = new int[capacity];
        size = 0;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x)
    {
        boolean contains = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<capacity; i++)
        {
            if(x == set[i])
                contains =  true;
            else
                contains = false;
        }
        return contains;
    }

    public void add(int x)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i<capacity; i++)
        {
            if(!contains(x))
            {
                if(size == capacity)
                {
                    set = Arrays.copyOf(set,size*2);
                }
                if(set[i]==0)
                {
                    set[i++] = x;
                }

            }
        }
        size++;
    }

    public boolean remove(int x)
    {
        boolean remove = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(x == set[i])
            {
                set[i] = set[size -1];
                size--;
                remove =  true;
            }
            if(isEmpty())
            {
               remove =  false;
            }
        }
        return remove;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        set = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if(size == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int[] toArray()
    {
        return Arrays.copyOf(set, capacity);
    }
}
```

This is the driver class that I test my class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SetDriver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SetDriver driver = new SetDriver();
        Set s1 = new Set(5);
        s1.add(2);
        s1.add(3);
        s1.add(4);
        driver.print(s1);
        System.out.println("Size: "+s1.size());
    }

   public static void print(Set s)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<s.toArray().length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(s.toArray()[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

The outputs are here:

```
2 3 2 3 2 
Size: 3
```

Comment: Remove `else contains = false;` from your `contains()` method.

Comment: Your `add()` method doesn't make sense. What's the loop for?

Comment: Your current contains method sets the `contains` variable only to `true` if the **last element** was equal since if not it will set it to `false` again at the last element, even if it was `true` before.

Answer (score 1):

There's a likely problem with your `contains` method.  Suppose that you *did* find a duplicate.  What happens is that you assign your variable to `true` and you *continue to iterate*.  This stomps over the logic entirely; you could have a duplicate but never act on it because your boolean code precludes you from doing so.

Ideally, when you find a match, you **must** stop iterating and return immediately.

```
public boolean contains(int value) {
    for(int setItem : set) {
        if(setItem == value) {
            return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `add` method like this.

```
public void add(int x) {
    if (contains(x))
        return;
    if (size >= capacity) {
        capacity *= 2;
        set = Arrays.copyOf(set, capacity);
    }
    set[size++] = x;
}
```